# PHP include file in class, wrong paths

Tags: php

I have class called client, and there i have function, in which i'm trying to include/execute php file, but when i'm doing it all path's in that file which i'm trying to include goes wrong.

class function:

```
public static function SendSSHCommand($ssh_cmd) {
        include('../Core/core_class.php');
        $ssh = new samp_panel();
        $ssh->SendCommand($ssh_cmd);
}
```

I would like get a solution, how to include file, that all directory path's in that file wouldn't go wrong.

I get many errors like that:

```
Warning: include(Net/SSH2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vlkg/domains/vlkg.lt/public_html/naujas/Core/core_class.php on line 30

Warning: include(Net/SSH2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vlkg/domains/vlkg.lt/public_html/naujas/Core/core_class.php on line 30

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Net/SSH2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:Core/NetModule') in /home/vlkg/domains/vlkg.lt/public_html/naujas/Core/core_class.php on line 30

Fatal error: Class 'Net_SSH2' not found in /home/vlkg/domains/vlkg.lt/public_html/naujas/Core/core_class.php on line 366
```

Comment: put your includes at the top of your file, not within functions

Comment: Also, note that an included file again includes files, relative file names will be resolved from the directory of the very first executed file.

Comment: use `__DIR__` at the start of your path

Comment: ok, now include works, but in that included file is class, when i'm trying to access that class it gives me error: Fatal error: Class 'ssh' not found in

Comment: @user3849197 Open up a different question for that.

Answer (score 0):

I always change my include directory when I run a script. For me it just makes it easier if I set a point of reference for all my included files.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Put something like this at the top of your file

```
set_include_path('/usr/www/2/main');
include('include1.php');
include('subdir_of_include_path/include2.php');
```

There are several options but this is the one I find useful with my projects. This way I force and know what my include path is.